# How to get the upperbound and lowerbound using NSRange in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsrange

I am having Swift code, need to get UpperBound and lowerBound. But in Objective C, I am not able to see the property or function for both Upper and lower Bound to get its value.

Snippet:

```
{
let upperBound =  firstAppearance?.upperBound;
let lowerBound =  firstAppearance?.lowerBound;
}
```

**Where firstAppearence is Range.**

Can anyone help me to get the Upper and lower Bound value from NSRange using Objective-C.

Comment: try to access the `location` and `length` member of NSRange.

Comment: @StanOu: I can able access location and length using NSRange. I need to know what exactly taken care in swift for Upper and lower bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSRange` is a simple struct with `location` and `length`. The closest equivalent you'll get to Swift's `Range` is:

```
NSUInteger lowerBounds = range.location;
NSUInteger upperBounds = range.location + range.length;
```

<s>(N.B. This range contains the upper bound for non-empty ranges, unlike Swift's `Range`.)</s>

Comment: Really? I thought that was the primary difference between `ClosedRange` and `Range`. `ClosedRange` will always contain the upper bound, `Range` only contains it if it's empty (according to the docs).

Comment: Actually I guess `NSRange` doesn't really "contain" a location, it's all about what kind of check you use. If you're using `NSLocationInRange` then my last statement is wrong.

Comment: `NSRange(location: a, length: b)` describes the half-open interval `[a, a+b)`, excluding the upper bound.

Comment: I think Lower bound = range.location and upper bound = range.length. Because when I am printing swift Range it give me something like this: ▿ CountableRange(0..<65014)
  - lowerBound : 0
  - upperBound : 65014

Comment: @AbilashBNair then what happens if location is > 0? It's why you need `location + length`.